# RTK useQuery is not refetch after mutation the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am getting post data from database through RTK useQuery, but when i upload new post through useMutation, it dosn't update data on Screen first time. After load the page it shows data. How to do this to get data without load a page.

```
// this is get post RTK query function
`const getallPosts =  useGetallPostsQuery();

  const postData = async () => {
    if(getallPosts.currentData){
      getallPosts.currentData.data.posts.map(item => dispatch(setPost(item)))
      console.log(getallPosts.currentData.data)
    }
  };`
```

this is my Api file

```
`createPost:builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => {
        return {
          url: "create_post",
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        };
      },
    }),

    getallPosts: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: 'get_all_posts',
        method: 'GET',
        headers : {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        }
      }),
      providesTags : ['Posts']
    }),`
```

i tried tags caching but it didn't worked